# Javascript and Electron Js | window.location.pathname error

Tags: javascript, electron

```
function onclick () {

   window.location.pathname = "home/userıd/desktop/project folder/src/html/index.html" }
```

This code working !

but

```
function onclick () {

   window.location.pathname = "/src/html/index.html" }
```

it doesn't work and I'm in  project folder right now

Comment: What is the current `location.href`?

Comment: That's my fault, I was looking in the wrong place. console.log(location.href) with command, problem solved  Thank you